# copy ROI from one image and copy to on another image in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, image-processing

I want to develop a function with the following signature:

```
 CopyImage(ImageSource inputImage, Point inTopLeft, Point InBottomRight, ImageSource outputImage, Point outTopLeft);
```

This function copy part of input image (ROI defined by inTopLeft and inBottomRight) and copy it to outputImage at outTopLeft.

I can do this in WPF by manipulating pixels, but I am looking for a solution that can do it much faster.

What is the fastest way to do this in WPF?

Comment: When you say "manipulating pixels", you mean [BitmapSource.CopyPixels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.copypixels(v=vs.110).aspx) from the source and [WriteableBitmap.WritePixels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Media.Imaging.WriteableBitmap.WritePixels(v=vs.110).aspx) to the target? That would be pretty fast.

Comment: @Clemens No, I was thinking of getting each pixel and placing it to output. But this method seems very fast. Do you have any sample? If you, add it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method could look like this:

```
private BitmapSource CopyRegion(
    BitmapSource sourceBitmap, Int32Rect sourceRect,
    BitmapSource targetBitmap, int targetX, int targetY)
{
    if (sourceBitmap.Format != targetBitmap.Format)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException(
            "Source and target bitmap must have the same PixelFormat.");
    }

    var bytesPerPixel = (sourceBitmap.Format.BitsPerPixel + 7) / 8;
    var stride = bytesPerPixel * sourceRect.Width;
    var pixelBuffer = new byte[stride * sourceRect.Height];
    sourceBitmap.CopyPixels(sourceRect, pixelBuffer, stride, 0);

    var outputBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(targetBitmap);
    sourceRect.X = targetX;
    sourceRect.Y = targetY;
    outputBitmap.WritePixels(sourceRect, pixelBuffer, stride, 0);

    return outputBitmap;
}
```

Comment: Better yet, use CroppedBitmap class.

Comment: @Aybe And then get the pixel buffer from there to copy over the target? Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Using it you would save yourself doing a manual copy. On your code you never write to `targetBitmap`, did you forget something ?

Comment: @Aybe You might have tested the code before commenting. Take a look at the WriteableBitmap constructor argument. It *creates a copy* of targetBitmap, before the copied rectange is written over it. And using CroppedBitmap would *still require to get its pixel buffer* by calling CopyPixels, so it's redundant.