# Generating tiles from BitmapImage

Tags: wpf, bitmapimage, tile

I am generating tiles from very large images to use with leaflet. I have a working solution that uses System.Drawing.Bitmap and loads the image from file. I already have the image in memory as a BitmapImage however, and would like to reuse it for memory purposes since these images can be very large. But I can not find a good way of doing this with BitmapImage.

What I basically need is something equivalent of

`GraphicsHandle.DrawImage(sourceImage, destinationRect, sourceRect, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);`

I need to crop and resize a part of the image, and draw this onto another image in a specified location and then save this to file. What is the best way of doing this using BitmapImage?

Comment: Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20024774/1136211).

Comment: That example only crops, it does not resize the cropped area to fit the resulting image. Imagine cropping 1000x1000 pixels into a 256x256 image at position 128,128, so sourceRect is (0,0,1000,100) and destRect is (128,128,128,128).

Comment: Also the solution should not allocate more than MemoryOf(CroppedRegion) + MemoryOf(DestinationRegion)